# sed remove last space only on end of line,combined with awk

Tags: sed, awk

I have those line

```
Siouxsie Sioux  Siouxsie Sioux  ...     
Sylvia Tobias   Sylvia Tobias   ...     
Sydney Urshan   Sydney Urshan   ... 
Club Drummer (uncredited)   Club Drummer (uncredited)   ...
```

With awk i print first column tab separated and i add a ,

```
awk -F "\t" '{print $1","}'
```

is ok,but i see blank space at end so i use sed

```
awk -F "\t" '{print $1","}'|sed -r 's/(^[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+[^[:blank:]]+)[[:blank:]]+/\1/'
```

With this is ok,but remove also the second white space,so

```
Club Drummer (uncredited) ,
```

become

```
Club Drummer(uncredited),
```

i want

```
Club Drummer (uncredited),
```

So how to remove the last space only?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F ' *\t' '{print $1 ","}'
```

Or:

```
sed $'s/ *\t.*/,/'
```

Answer (score 2):

Strip those trailing spaces using `awk` itself

```
awk -F'\t' '{sub(/[[:blank:]]+$/, "", $1);print $1","}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `printf` instead of using `print` to get around this problem.

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++)printf("%s ", $i);printf("\b%s\n",",")}' file.txt 
Siouxsie Sioux Siouxsie Sioux,
Sylvia Tobias Sylvia Tobias,
Sydney Urshan Sydney Urshan,
Club Drummer (uncredited) Club Drummer (uncredited),
```

Or if you need it with `sed`

```
$ sed -re 's/ +\.\.+/,/g' file.txt 
Siouxsie Sioux  Siouxsie Sioux,     
Sylvia Tobias   Sylvia Tobias,     
Sydney Urshan   Sydney Urshan, 
Club Drummer (uncredited)   Club Drummer (uncredited),
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the whole operation could be completed using `sed 's/^\([^\t]*\).*/\1,/'`...

Comment: Why have I been downvoted?